# Kodi error after dist-upgrade. Unable to open display

Tags: display, kodi, update

I've run a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade kodi on Raspbian Jessie. After this when I try to launch with `kodi --standalone` I get these errors. What can I do?

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/**init**.py:57:
>   GtkWarning: could not open display   warnings.warn(str(e),
>   _gtk.Warning)
>
> Error: unable to open display
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:69: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
>   window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:69: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion
>   'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed   window =
>   gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:83: GtkWarning:
>   IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)'
>   failed   button = gtk.Button("Quit")
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:83: Warning: g_object_get: assertion
>   'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed   button = gtk.Button("Quit")
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: GtkWarning: Screen for GtkWindow not set;
>   you must always set a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
>   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: GtkWarning:
>   IA__gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN
>   (screen)' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning:
>   pango_context_set_font_description: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
>   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_base_dir:
>   assertion 'context != NULL' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_language:
>   assertion 'context != NULL' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning: pango_layout_new: assertion
>   'context != NULL' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_text:
>   assertion 'layout != NULL' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_alignment:
>   assertion 'layout != NULL' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_ellipsize:
>   assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning:
>   pango_layout_set_single_paragraph_mode: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT
>   (layout)' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_width:
>   assertion 'layout != NULL' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning: pango_layout_get_extents:
>   assertion 'layout != NULL' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_attributes:
>   assertion 'layout != NULL' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: GtkWarning:
>   IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN
>   (screen)' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_colormap_get_visual:
>   assertion 'GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window:
>   assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed   window.show_all ()
>
> /usr/share/kodi/FEH.py:88: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_window_new: assertion
>   'GDK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed   window.show_all () Segmentation
>   fault

Comment: Is there anything unusual about your setup aside from these errors? How are you using the Pi - with a directly attached monitor and keyboard, or via SSH, or via VNC, or something else?

Comment: I'm using it via SSH, I've noticed that during the upgrade it failed to install the confluence skin package. I've re-run dist-upgrade and the package was succesfully installed but the error is still there.

Comment: Is there actually a display connected?

Comment: Yes, It's connected to a tv. I've also tried to reboot the pi and the tv works. I've tried to launch kodi but I get the error shown above. I've not tried to launch it directly on the pi with a keyboard but I've never had problems launching kodi via ssh